# responsive bootstrap css php error

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

this is the problem and what i need:

[image]

the code for my website project please help me to fix this problem :( 
what is the problem exactly ??? and how can i fix it 
thanks.

```
<?php
include 'init.php';
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
$stmt->execute();     
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>

<!-- fb like and share js code -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-title text-center">
            <h1>Dernière images</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php 
          foreach ($rows as $image) {
            echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 ">';
                echo '<div class="thumbnail">';
                echo      '<h2 class="h4">'.$image['Name']. '</h2>';
                echo      '<div class="main">';
                echo      '<img src="data:image;base64,'.$image['Image'].' " alt="image name" title="image title" width="250" height="250" >';
                echo      '<div class="mask">';
                echo           '<div class="author">';
                echo              '<p>par<spane>oussama</spane></p>';
                echo           '</div>';
                echo           '<div class="focus">';
                echo                '<img class="img-focus" src="layout/images/search.png">';
                echo           '</div>';
                echo           '<div class="date">';
                echo                   '<p><span>14-05-2016</span><span>16:22</span></p>';
                echo            '</div>';
                echo       '</div>';
                echo   '</div>';
                echo      '<table class="table table-bordered">';
                echo          '<tr>';
                echo              '<td><div class="fb-like" data-href="https://fowajproject.com" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div></td>';

                echo              '<td><div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://fowajproject.com" data-layout="button" data-mobile-iframe="true"></div></td>';

                echo              '<td><img class="center-block" alt="image title" src="layout/images/info/eye.png"></td>';
                echo          '</tr>';
                echo      '</table>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
          }
        ?>

    </div>

    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="disabled"><a href="#" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">6 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">7 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">8 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">9 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">10 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li class="disabled"><a href="#" aria-label="next"><span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <?php include $tpl . 'footer.php';?>
```

please verify with me the problem.

Comment: this is because of height difference of divs. you can try with fix height?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use [Masonry Plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

---

Or you can limit the heights of the blocks and images:

Add additional class to this html line

`<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 card-item">`

And add code to the css:

```
.card-item {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.card-item .thumbnail {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: Masonry is the way to go for this layout.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common situation. For such cases Bootstrap provides [responsive column resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets):

> With the four tiers of grids available you're bound to run into issues where, at certain breakpoints, your columns don't clear quite right as one is taller than the other. To fix that, use a combination of a `.clearfix` and our [responsive utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).

So you need to add two kinds of blocks in the layout:

- Add `<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>` block after each 4 columns.
- Add `<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>` block after each 3 columns.

For example:

```
    <?php
      counter = 0;
      foreach ($rows as $image) {
        echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 ">';
        // ... here is the code of the thumbnail ...
        echo '</div>';

        counter += 1;
        if (counter % 4 == 0) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>';
        if (counter % 3 == 0) echo '<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>';
      }
    ?>
```